# Wrong width and height after upload to server

Tags: php

#### Source image

http://i.imgur.com/TbffELG.jpg

This is a vertical image, but when I upload it to server, server got the size width="3264" height="1836", and my resize and crop function will be wrong

there is the demo site http://demo.chan15.info/im/

#### PHP code

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES['file'];
$tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
$imageInfo = getimagesize($tmp);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($imageInfo); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I have the same Problem. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the photo was taken on a mobile phone it can apply meta data regarding the orientation of the device at the time, which is used to infer the correct way to display the image. Not all decoders support the meta data, and will display the image incorrectly. In this case your image will probably display on its side.

You either need an image library capable of dealing with this meta data, or you can transform the image and/or remove the meta data. Apologies, but I can't suggest a suitable image library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. As HenryTK said the central problem is that the orientation of the picture is stored in the EXIF data (used by modern cameras and smartphones) while the width and length information indicate a landscape picture.

My solution is to open the picture with GIMP. GIMP shows the following modal dialog:

[image]

Now you only have to click the rotate button and save the picture.

It's not the best solution. If somebody has a script or something please tell me.